# how to prevent an attachment of .frm files to another server

Tags: mysql

if you copy .frm files of mysql database to another server, you will be able to get the table structure. This means if someone get access to my server and copy .frm files the person will see my table structure when it is attached to his server. this obviously makes it unsecure. How do you prevent that from happening?
hiding the path does not solve the problem because the .frm file can be searched.

Is there a mechanism that will generate an error when the file is attached to a different server?

Comment: only the mysql user should have access rights for the mysql data directory. if somone really gets (root) access to your server, you have bigger problem then just jour data scheme.

Comment: Beware of what you wish or you'll lose your data when you upgrade your hard disc drive ;-P

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is not that important for security. Getting the table structure is only a security threat if you have other security problems in your code. What you should be really worried about is how someone got to your .frm files in the first place because that means they have access to your database server, and hence possibly all your database data. The schema is the least of your problems.

When people have access to files on your server the battle is already lost. They should not get that far in the first place. Therefore make sure you secure your SSH server, file servers etc.

Comment: If I was a cracker I'd probably prefer a credit card number to `CHAR(16)`.